# Set expectedExceptions using dataprovider

Tags: java, exception, testng, expected-exception, testng-dataprovider

Is it possible to set the `expectedExceptions` option in a TestNG `@Test` from a `@DataProvider`? If so, how is it done?

Here is a non-intuitive example:

```
@DataProvider
private Object[][] methodABadArgsProvider() {
    return new Object[][] {
      {null, "arg2", "arg3"}, // expect NullPointerException
      {"arg1", null, "arg3"}, // expect IllegalArgumentException
      {"arg1", "arg2", null} // expect OperationNotSupportedException
    }
}

@Test(expectedException = [tbd].class, dataProvider = "methodABadArgsProvider")
public void methodABadArgs(String arg1, String arg2, String arg3) {
    testInstance.methodA(arg1, arg2, arg3);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataProvider has access to test context. It's not possible to it via dp; but you can use AnnotationTransformer if it allows to do what you need.